# How to access RowDataPacket mysql-node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

```
connection.query('
SET @update_id := 0; 
UPDATE relations set x1 = ?, y1 = ?, id = (SELECT @update_id := id) WHERE element_to =?;
SELECT @update_id;',[data.x2,data.y2,id],function(err,result){
if(err){console.error(err);}
else{console.log(result);console.log(result.@update_id);}
});
```

I am getting the following result from a query execution:

```
[ RowDataPacket {
  '@update_id': 'WAbWA1WA5WA2WA8WAdWA4WA9' } ] ]
```

How do I access the **@update_id** field to store the value in a variable. I know these are objects and I tried the following to access them such as follows:

```
results.@update_id;
```

But I get undefined when I try to log the value. How to get the value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a RowDataPacket object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221980/how-to-access-a-rowdatapacket-object)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
results[0].@update_id
```

Answer (score 2):

use `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));`

then if you want to get access data on variable

```
var data = JSON.stringify(result[0].@update_id)
console.log(data);
```

you can't use index on var E.G

`console.log(data[0].@update_id)` it is wrong

Answer (score 2):

just conver the result to array, then you can easily access the data, i get solved by doing this

```
let res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
```