# How to convert this mysql select return into one array

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, object

Is there anyway to convert this like the example below?

**Convert this:**

```
[
  RowDataPacket { title: 'Code' },
  RowDataPacket { title: 'Pizza' }
]
```

**Into this:**

```
['Code', 'Pizza']
```

Comment: That's not even an valid `array`.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia Whoops forgot the '

Comment: by using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): `yourArray.map(rdp => rdp.title)`. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31229034/6567275

Comment: @Thomas I feel stupid, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I've provided you two possible solutions, in case if it's just an array of objects or an array of nested objects.

```js
var arr = [{RowDataPacket: { title: 'Code' }}, {RowDataPacket: { title: 'Pizza' }}],
    res = arr.map(v => v.RowDataPacket.title);
    console.log(res);
```

```js
var arr = [{ title: 'Code' }, { title: 'Pizza' }],
    res = arr.map(v => v.title);
    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a new array

```
var newArr = [];
```

And then push each item into the array

```
result.forEach(function(obj){
   newArr.push(obj.title);
}
```

Comment: foreach should be forEach() - but I can't make such a short edit :)