# How to get a RowDataPacket object from MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

I would like to get the amount of a MySQL-database, then I query "`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles_table`" and got "[ RowDataPacket { 'COUNT(*)': 13 } ]"

I have tried to 'console.log(data[0].COUNT)', but I got a undefined message....

Could anyone tell me How do I do to get the number 13 with javascript?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can store the value in php variable then just echo to the javascript variable.

Comment: possible duplication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221980/how-to-access-a-rowdatapacket-object

Comment: I have tried to 'console.log(data[0].COUNT)', but I got a undefined message....@Christian Felix

Comment: sorry...I know  Javascript only@Bibhudatta Sahoo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, give the aliases to your expression column in SELECT statement i.e. for "COUNT(*)" as below.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM articles_table
```

Then, try to use

```
console.log(data[0].cnt)
```