# convert rowdatapacket into array , How to convert mysql node.js api rowdatapacket to array , string to array

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, node.js, string

please help me to convert my rowdatapacket into array of array or nested array

enter code here

```
router.get('/getPosts/:user_id', (req, res, next) => {

connection.query('SELECT * FROM files WHERE user_id = ?', [req.params.user_id], (err, rows, fields) => {
  if (!err) {

    resultArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));

    console.log(resultArray);

    return res.status(200).send(resultArray);
  } else {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(404).send('Sorry user_id does not exits');
  }
 })
});
```

OUTPUT

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a RowDataPacket object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221980/how-to-access-a-rowdatapacket-object)

Answer (score 0):

OutPut:

{ post_id: 17,
    user_id: 1,
    description: ' Hi How are you ',
    file_name: 'iron_man_5k_2.jpg,iron_man_captain.jpg',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg,image/jpeg',
    size: '5696459,180',
    saved_name:
     '1546438737564_iron_man_5k_2.jpg,1546438737672_iron_man_captain.jpg',
    file_path:
     'uploads1546438737564_iron_man_5k_2.jpg,uploads1546438737672_iron_man_captain.jpg',
    created: '2019-01-02T14:18:57.000Z' }