# Is there a way to create NestJS API without typeorm but plain expressJS/mysql methods?

Tags: typescript, express, nestjs, mysqljs

I have been trying to create an API in `nestJS` using just plain `expressJS` and `mysql` **without using `typeorm`**. However, there's little to no information for this either in the documentation or other sources.

What I have done so far:

1. Created a global variable for holding connection received from `mysql.createConnection()`.
2. Tried to use this connection to get values from db:

```js
async findAll() {
    return await connection.query('SELECT * from test', (error, results, fields) => {
        console.log(results);
        return results;
    });
}
```

The console is printing this data:

```js
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'test',
    middleName: '1',
    lastName: 'user' },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 2,
    firstName: 'test',
    middleName: '2',
    lastName: 'user' }
]
```

However it is also throwing this error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON 
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

**EDIT:**

I tried this solution from the link **@Kim Kern** suggested:

```js
return await connection.query('SELECT * from users', (error, results, fields) => {
    results = results.map((result) => {
        return Object.assign({}, result);
    });
    console.log(results);
    return results;
});
```

Now the results do not have `RowDataPacket`, but still throw the same error.

Comment: The problem seems to be `RowDataPacket`. Have a look at this thread, it proposes a hacky solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34460319/4694994

Comment: Also, have a look at the docs that use typeorm without the `@nestjs/typeorm` package. I think you can reuse a lot of the structures and just swap typeorm with mysql: https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/sql-typeorm

Answer (score 1):

Finally !! after digging for hours I got it. The problem is with the callback, it's not returning the desired Promise. It's Returning an Unparsable JSON.

Basically, What You have to do is.

```
async getAll(){
 const res = await this.execExec(connection)
 return res;
}

execExec(connection){
 return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    connection.query('SELECT * from users', function (error,results,fields) {
      if (error) throw error;
      results = results.map((result) => {
         return Object.assign({}, result);
    });
      console.log(results);
      res(results);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
export class TestService {
async selectAll(): Promise<any> {
        let connection = mysql.createPool({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: 'root',
            database: 'testDB'
        });
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            connection.execute("select * from test", (e, results) => {
                if (e) throw e;
                //  console.log(results);
                res(results);
            });
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.