# How to read results returned by a query when using mysql in nodejs server?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have something like this:

```
      var sql = "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM files)";

      var query = db.query(sql, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result[0]);
      });
```

console.log returns:
`RowDataPacket { 'EXISTS(SELECT * FROM files)': 1 }`

Looks like this is a key-value pair? how do i access the value in this case?

I did come across this: [How to access a RowDataPacket object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221980/how-to-access-a-rowdatapacket-object). but in my case since the property is a string I am not sure how to access it.

Comment: I did come across that, but i am not sure what the user_id they refer to is!? i dont see it in my logs. Please educate me if this stupid.

Comment: In that question, it's a property of the object. Here, `EXISTS(SELECT * FROM files)` is a property of your object. Do the same thing.

Comment: there the supposed answer is to do results[0].user_id. but in my case the property is a string. how can i use this?