# Node JS+Express: How to define and use MySQL data in HTML(EJS)?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, express

I created a simple rest-api app(nodeJS+ExpressJS+MySQL) as a test project.
It's functioning well, so I wanted to add HTML(EJS) to display the data so I have been working on displaying views.
However, I wasn't able to pass on MySQL Data to HTML.

** As I'm still learning nodeJS, I'm still confused as some tutorials added routers in app.js/server.js

Since I have created `getAll()` in the controller, I used `Restaurant.getAll()` in `server.js`.
Below is the console.log result of `Restaurant.getAll()`. I tried to used `JSON.stringtify(data)` already, but there's no difference.

I would appreciate if anyone could let me how I could change or fix my codes.
Appreciate all your helps.

```js
restaurant_list:  [
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    name: 'A',
    genre: 'Japanese',
    rating: 4
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 2,
    name: 'B',
    genre: 'Mexican',
    rating: 4
  },
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 3,
    name: 'C',
    genre: 'Chinese',
    rating: 4
  }
]
```

server.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const Restaurant = require("./app/models/restaurant.model.js");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json()); //Used to parse JSON bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded()); //Parse URL-encoded bodies

// set the view engine to ejs
app.set('views', './app/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// simple route
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  var data = Restaurant.getAll();
  res.render("index.ejs", { data: data });
});

require("./app/routes/restaurant.routes.js")(app);

// set port, listen for requests
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000.");
});
```

restaurant.model.js

```js
const sql = require("./db.js");

// constructor
const Restaurant = function(restaurant) {
    this.name = restaurant.name;
    this.genre = restaurant.genre;
    this.rating = restaurant.rating;
};

Restaurant.getAll = result => {
  sql.query("SELECT * FROM restaurant_list", (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(null, err);
      return;
    }

    console.log("restaurant_list: ", res);
    result(null, res);
  });
};

module.exports = Restaurant;
```

restaurant.routes.js

```js
module.exports = app => {
    const restaurant_list = require("../controllers/restaurant.controller.js");
  
    // Retrieve all restaurants
    app.get("/", restaurant_list.findAll);

  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your orginal question, it seems that the response you got is accessible as a normal object (ref: [How to access a RowDataPacket object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221980/how-to-access-a-rowdatapacket-object)) and that `RowDataPacket` is just the constructor name of the object response.

Thus you are not using the callback return of the function `getAll`. You are passing it a callback named `result` and returning the standard `(err, result)`. But you are treating it as normal synchronous function. Change this:

```js
// simple route
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  var data = Restaurant.getAll();
  res.render("index.ejs", { data: data });
});
```

To this:

```js
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  Restaurant.getAll(function(err, data) {
    if (err) // handle your error case
    else {
      res.render("index.js", { data: data });
    }
  });
});
```

And even better (es6 syntax):

```js
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  Restaurant.getAll((err, data) => {
    if (err) // handle your error case
    else res.render("index.js", { data });
  });
});
```

Using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring).

Be careful because in the err callback of your getAll function you are returning `(null, err)` and you should return `result(err)` as the second parameter is not needed since you should always check for `err` first.

Also, as an advice, i would like to suggest you to use standard javascript [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) instead of doing the same thing on a normal `constant` object. Also, you could get rid of the callbacks in your controller functions and treat your query as asynchronous calls [like this](https://codeburst.io/node-js-mysql-and-async-await-6fb25b01b628).

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! I tried access it normally from EJS (using data[0].name, data.restaurant_list.name, data.name) but it always ended up with an error, stating that "Cannot read property '0'/'restaurant_list'/name' of undefined". And thanks for advice about using classes and asynchronous calls. I will try it after solving the current issues.

Comment: @lane3445 edited my answer as i found your issue

Comment: Thanks alot! It works perfectly! I tried a different approach, but this looks more cleaner.