# How to get only the value of a stringified MySQL query result?

Tags: mysql, node.js, stringify

After executing this query:

```
con.query("SELECT name FROM members WHERE id=1", function(err, rows, fields) {
   console.log(rows); 
});
```

this is what I get:

```
[ RowDataPacket { name: 'John' } ]
```

I expect only one record and I only want to get `John`. How do I do that?

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221980/how-to-access-a-rowdatapacket-object

Comment: actually Im getting this outside the console `[{ name: 'John' }]` and this is what I want to get the value from.

Comment: `console.log(rows.length ? rows[0].name : '');`

Answer (score 1):

Short of writing your own additional function(s) and passing the `row` object through them your desired result format is not possible based on the design of the `mysqljs/mysql` package. In a standard `SELECT` query the result is always an object.

There is a bit of a hack workaround by using the `stream` function. Below is an example, but you will still end up with more lines of code than you would if you simply accessed the value via `rows[0].name` in a standard query.

```js
let the_query = con.query('SELECT name FROM members WHERE id = 1;');
the_query
.on('result', function(row) {
  console.log('row.name:', row.name);
  // expected in log:
  // row.name: John
})
.on('end', function() {
  // this chained event can be excluded
  // here for demo purposes
  console.log('all done');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
JSON.stringify(RowDataPacket[0].name)
```

This will output:

> John

Comment: RowDataPacket is the type, not the variable name