# Convert array [ {''} ] to list [ '']

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I would like to convert array to a list like :

```
This :
[ RowDataPacket { id_name: '' } ]


To : 
[ '' ]
```

I just want a list, whitout name, no 'id_name'

Comment: this does not looks like javascript

Comment: This is a repeated question I think:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221980/how-to-access-a-rowdatapacket-object

Comment: Yes, it's a SQL array, but I want to convert it to do something after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new empty array and when looping your rowDataPacket array, push them to new array.

Example;

```
// your array = rowDataPackets =[{id_name:''},{id_name:''},...]

const CleanArray = [];

rowDataPackets.forEach( ({ id_name : idName }) => { CleanArray.push(idName) });

console.log(CleanArray);

// CleanArray = ['','',...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Map Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over this arr and get the key

```
const result = [ RowDataPacket { id_name: '' } ].map( item => item.id_name )
```